# Asynchronous callback "Async End called with an IAsyncResult from a different Begin method. Parameter name: result"

Tags: wcf, asynchronous

I can't figure out why this is.

I have a connect method that works fine:

```
public void Connect()
{
    _client.BeginConnect(new AsyncCallback(this.ConnectCallback), _client);
}

public void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    ServerClient callback = null;

        callback = (ServerClient)asyncResult.AsyncState;
        callback.EndConnect(asyncResult);

        Program.IMMainForm.BeginInvoke(new frmMain.ConnectionEstablishedNotification(Program.IMMainForm.ConnectionEstablished));
```

This works totally fine. I pretty much copied and pasted this code for my Send method:

```
public void Send(string code, string data)
{
    _client.BeginSendToServer((code + data), new AsyncCallback(this.SendCallback), _client);
}


public void SendCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    ServerClient callback = null;

        callback = (ServerClient)asyncResult.AsyncState;
        callback.EndConnect(asyncResult);
}
```

However it errors on the EndConnect line with the error

"Async End called with an IAsyncResult from a different Begin method. 
Parameter name: result"

saying

A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

I'm not 100% on async stuff so is there something obvious I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be calling `EndSendToServer`, not `EndConnect`.

Generated async methods are paired with the `Begin` and `End` prefixes; you begin the async operation with one method and end it with the other.